# Can reflection extract initial values used in a trait?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I am playing with reflection to achieve a deep analysis on a trait. One of the things I would like to get is the initial value set to a member field. For example, in the trait:

```
trait A {
  val x: Int = 3
  val y: String = "y"
}
```

it would be nice to know 3 and "y". I have not found anything related to this task in the API, and due to the following output (generated by scalac -Xprint):

```
abstract trait A extends Object {
  <accessor> def com$hablapps$A$_setter_$x_=(x$1: Int): Unit;
  <accessor> def com$hablapps$A$_setter_$y_=(x$1: String): Unit;
  <stable> <accessor> def x(): Int;
  <stable> <accessor> def y(): String
};
abstract trait A$class extends  {
  def /*A$class*/$init$($this: com.hablapps.A): Unit = {
    $this.com$hablapps$A$_setter_$x_=(3);
    $this.com$hablapps$A$_setter_$y_=("y");
    ()
  }
}
```

I am afraid it is going to be quite hard to access them, since they are kept in the $init$ method's body. Is there any (easy) way to get those values with reflection?

Comment: I forgot to say that I have been following this [article](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/json-serialization-with-reflection-in.html), which has been really useful to extract a lot of information from the trait.

Comment: I am not familiar with Scala reflection, but if you are able execute ``new A {}.x``, then you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, instantiate and get the values, through reflection or not. And hope there isn't any side-effects.

Comment: Yes, it will work for sure in that case, but I concealed some details: The reflection is working inside a function which receives the trait as a type parameter (`analyze[T]`) and it is not mandatory for the trait to come with initial values. As a result, generating the instance can get quite complicated and I was looking for something cleaner. Anyway, I have not thought in this simple solution until now, and perhaps, it is interesting to take it into account if anything else fails. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disassemble the bytecode:

```
trait A { val x: Int = 3 }

public abstract class A$class extends java.lang.Object{
public static void $init$(A);
  Code:
   0:    aload_0
   1:    iconst_3
   2:    invokeinterface #12,  2; //InterfaceMethod A.A$_setter_$x_$eq:(I)V
   7:    return
```

See line 1--the only place the value exists is in the bytecode for the init method!

You cannot get to this any other way, since if you have

```
trait A { val x: Int = 3 }
trait B extends A { override val x = 7 }
class C extends B {}
```

you find that `C` extends `A$_setter_$x_$eq` to do nothing at all--making the `A$class.$init$` call a no-op and rendering the value unretrievable.

Proof:

```
public class C extends java.lang.Object implements B,scala.ScalaObject{
public void A$_setter_$x_$eq(int);
  Code:
   0:    return

public void B$_setter_$x_$eq(int);
  Code:
   0:    aload_0
   1:    iload_1
   2:    putfield #11; //Field x:I
   5:    return
```

Comment: Yes, `C` is missing the 3, but it still have available the overriding 7, which becomes `C`'s initial value. So, in case of being analyzing this class, I will not care about the `A` initial value neither. Instead, I would like to know 7. Anyway, this is really interesting stuff. How did you generate that output?

Comment: @JesúsLópez That's done with `javap`. There's even a `:javap` command on REPL, but it requires `tools.jar` from JDK to be on the class path, and it only works for pre-compiled stuff, not for things you define on REPL itself.

Comment: @JesúsLópez - What do you mean "initial value"?  It's a val.  It can't change.  If `C` overrides `A` directly, it's the same story as if `B` does--the value may well be only in the bytecode, and is inaccessible because `A$_setter_$x_$eq` is overridden.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - `:javap` _will_ work on things you define in the REPL; it's just a little fussy about it because it gives precedence to the first thing of a given name (not the current one in scope), can't access auxiliary classes, and has a few other quirks.

Comment: @RexKerr Well, I never got it to work. It gives me `Could not find class bytes for 'myclass'`.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - I wonder if it's platform dependent?  I've never tried `:javap` on anything but Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can introspect to this point. That's not information about the type, but code. If you have the tree for the trait, you can find it out, but, otherwise, I doubt it.

You can use, however, class file parsers to investigate this further. I assume these would appear as constants for the class, which can be read. I'm not sure you could associate them with the variable, but...

I'm not much familiar with class file parsers, but I think a tool called "asm" does that.

Comment: Yes, I reached the conclussion that having the tree will be great, but is there any way to get it from a TypeTag? Anyway, I will take a look at ASM. Thanks, Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's Proxy to create an instance of the trait that collects values from all calls to the trait's ...$*setter*$... methods. Here's a hackish example:

```
object Reflection {
  def traitInits(clazz : Class[_]) : Map[String, Object] = {
    var cl = clazz.getClassLoader
    if (cl == null) {
      cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
    }

    var init : Option[java.lang.reflect.Method] = None
    try {
      for (m <- cl.loadClass(clazz.getName + "$class").getMethods if init.isEmpty)
        if (m.getName == "$init$")
          init = Some(m)
    } catch {
      case e : Exception =>
    }

    if (init.isEmpty) return Map()

    var encodedToDecodedSetterNameMap = Map[String, String]()

    for (m <- clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
      val setterPrefix = clazz.getName.replace('.', '$') + "$_setter_$"
      val encoded = m.getName
      if (encoded.startsWith(setterPrefix)) {
        val decoded = encoded.substring(setterPrefix.length, encoded.length - 4)
        encodedToDecodedSetterNameMap += (encoded -> decoded)
      }
    }

    var result = Map[String, Object]()

    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler
    import java.lang.reflect.Proxy

    init.get.invoke(null, Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl, Array[Class[_]](clazz),
      new InvocationHandler {
        def invoke(proxy : Object,
                   method : java.lang.reflect.Method,
                   args : Array[Object]) = {
          encodedToDecodedSetterNameMap.get(method.getName) match {
            case Some(decodedName) => result += (decodedName -> args(0))
            case _                 =>
          }
          null
        }
      }))

    result
  }                                               //> traitInits: (clazz: Class[_])Map[String,Object]

  trait A {
    val x : Int = 3
    val y : String = "y"
  }

  traitInits(classOf[A])                          //> res0: Map[String,Object] = Map(x -> 3, y -> y)
}
```